# Is_single not working properly in genesis

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, genesis-theme-framework

I am currently creating a child theme for my website which uses Genesis as a parent theme. Now I am making single pages as per my choosing. So, I am removing the entry header from within HTML main and posting it after `entry-header`. my code looks like this.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'gp_page_header');

function gp_page_header(){
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    ?>
    <div class="post-hero" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, circle cover, rgba(100, 66, 255, 0.9) 15%, rgba(0, 108, 255, 0.9) 50%, rgba(12, 180, 206, 0.9) 85%), url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
        <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">', '</h1>' ); 
        genesis_post_info();
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
 }
```

If didn't want to create this style for homepage and should be only applied to single pages. Here is what i am doing now.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
if(is_single()) {
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'gp_page_header');

function gp_page_header(){
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    ?>
    <div class="post-hero" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, circle cover, rgba(100, 66, 255, 0.9) 15%, rgba(0, 108, 255, 0.9) 50%, rgba(12, 180, 206, 0.9) 85%), url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
        <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">', '</h1>' ); 
        genesis_post_info();
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
 }
}
```

But this way it doesn't work. If I use a conditional tag, it isn't working. I am confused at the moment. Also, I am using `front-page.php` as the template for home. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your `is_single()` should be in the function - `function gp_page_header() { if ( ! is_single() ) { return; } ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Please put your action `add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'gp_page_header');` in `if condition` not whole code.

```
if(is_single()){
  add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'gp_page_header');
}
```

**Your updated code:**

```
if(is_single()) {
  add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'gp_page_header');
}

function gp_page_header(){
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    ?>
    <div class="post-hero" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, circle cover, rgba(100, 66, 255, 0.9) 15%, rgba(0, 108, 255, 0.9) 50%, rgba(12, 180, 206, 0.9) 85%), url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
        <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">', '</h1>' ); 
        genesis_post_info();
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
 }
```